# Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in php script

Tags: php, warnings, xss

i have php script, when i executed this code, i got warning

> Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in home/public_html

i've added antixss function for security vulnerability , like this code below. how do i resolve this warning?

```
<?php
$email_to = ""; 
$email_subject = ""; 
$success = ""; 

function antixss($value)
{
    $xss = htmlspecialchars(trim($value));
    return $xss;
}


if(!isset($_POST['First_Name']) ||
   !isset($_POST['Last_Name']) 
    {
    died('Sorry, there appears to be a problem.');      
}
$first_name =antixss($_POST['First_Name']); 
$last_name = antixss($_POST['Last_Name']);
```

how do i resolve this warning? thanks

Comment: try `var_dump($value);`

Comment: hello i've tried your solutions but it's still not work :( but thank you so much with your answer

Comment: @user3154864 You should add the results of `var_dump($_POST)` to the question.

Comment: the result is Fatal error: Call to undefined function var_dum() in /home

Comment: `var_dump()` not `var_dum()`

Comment: should i remove antixss () in this code? $first_name =antixss($_POST['First_Name']); // required

Answer (score 1):

It appears the error is in your html and not in the php.

If `$_POST['First_Name']` is an array while it should not be, it is likely your html looks something like:

```
<input name="First_Name[]" ...>
                       ^^ here, remove this
```

Comment: hello 

i've tried your solutions but it's still not work.

this is my html script

    <li>
         <label for="First_Name">First Name *</label>
            <input type="text" name="First_Name" id="First_Name" size="40" value="" />
        </li>
        <li>
         <label for="Last_Name">Last Name *</label>
            <input type="text" name="Last_Name" id="Last_Name" size="40" value="" />

        </li>


but thank you so much with your answer

Comment: my html code like this <input name="First_Name" ...> <input name="Last_Name" ...>

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your IF statement is all messed up

```
if(!isset($_POST['First_Name']) || !isset($_POST['Last_Name']) || 
    {
    died('Sorry, there appears to be a problem.');      
}
```

You start it with a bracket, you end it with an OR sign (`||`). First repair that, to something like this:

```
if(!isset($_POST['First_Name']) || !isset($_POST['Last_Name'])){
    died('Sorry, there appears to be a problem.');
}
```

Then, if the problem persists type in `var_dump($value)` and/or `var_dump($_POST)` inside the `antixss()` function so it's something like this

```
function antixss($value){
    var_dump($value); var_dump($_POST); exit();
    $xss = htmlspecialchars(trim($value));
    return $xss;
}
```

And tell us what the output is.

Comment: i've changed this code and still error the output is:
string(5) "john" array(10) { ["First_Name"]=> string(5) "john" ["Last_Name"]=> string(7) "doe"
but thanks for your help

Comment: should i remove antixss in this code? $first_name =antixss($_POST['First_Name']);